# Run Function If Div Element Does Not Contain HTML Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html

currently I am working with JavaScript, HTML, and jQuery.

Let's say I have a table and if I double click the "tr" element, then it will run a function (Update()), which will generate a textfield. But I am a bit confused, about how to run the function(Update()) if only there are not html tag within the div.

Here is my code:

```
function update(id) {
    for (i = 0, j = 8; i < j; i++) {
        con = $('#div-' + i).html();
        if (con != "") {
            $('#div-' + i).html("<input type = text class=erf id = gn_" + id + " value=" + con + ">")
            if (i == 5 || i == 6) {
                $(this).addAttr("disabled");
            }
        } else {
            if ($('#int_' + id).is(':checked')) {
                $('.r1').html("<input name = tp class=tp id = int type =radio checked>")
            } else {
                $('.r1').html("<input name = tp class=tp id = ext type =radio>")
            }

            if ($('#ext_' + id).is(':checked')) {
                $('.r2').html("<input name = tp class=tp id = int type =radio checked>")
            } else {
                $('.r2').html("<input name = tp class=tp id = ext type =radio>")
            }

            if ($('#dp_' + id).is(':checked')) {
                $('.r3').html("<input name = tp class=tp id = int type =radio checked>")
            } else {
                $('.r3').html("<input name = tp class=tp id = dp type =radio>")
            }
        }
    }
    $('#divb-' + id).html("<input type = button value = Update class= 'button-mid ch' id=" + col[8] + ">")
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: And what's not working with the way you're doing it now, checking if the innerHTML has length ?

Comment: Can you include a snippet of the html? The answer below is a perfect way of checking if the div has no html elements in it...'selector' being a reference to the div, not the tr...not sure why it was down-voted

Comment: @ted yeah, the answer bellow is perfect and work for me. Thanks :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check the `length` of all the children elements. If it's 0, there are no children HTML elements:

```
if ( $("selector").children().length == 0 )
```